# Finding a certain average - Ruby, JS or Python

Tags: javascript, python, ruby

Had this one come up at work and thought I'd throw it to the world.

Given a float, e.g. `1.722`, return the average of the preceding whole odd integer and the following whole odd integer. The answer to this float would be `2`, or the average between `1` and `3`.

**EDIT**: If the float is a whole odd integer (e.g. `3.00`), then the answer must consider it to be the lower of the two odd numbers to be averaged. Thanks for bringing that one up in the comments.

May the Force be with you.

Comment: So, round up to the next even?

Comment: Hey sorry guys, you were all over it! Just posted our three attempts. (There was an error in my formatting when trying to submit our answers.)

Comment: What if the float *is* an odd integer?

Comment: @user2357112, such as 3.00?

Comment: @AnthonyDGardner: Yes, that would be one possible odd integer.

Comment: @user2357112: Great point. I hadn't considered that case. If that happens, then it immediately becomes the lower range whole integer. (e.g. 3.00 would result in 4, the average of 3 and 5.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I think this question belongs in the codegolf stack exchange,
I will  provide an answer in javascript

```
function findAverage (a){
    return 2*Math.floor(Math.ceil(a)/2);
  }
```

Edit : If it is an odd number and is taken as the lower of the 2 numbers I would simply change the order of ceiling and floor function

```
function findAverage (a){
        return 2*Math.ceil(Math.floor(a)/2);
      }
```

It will give 4 for 3.00

Comment: Codegolf? Shoot, I didn't even know that was a thing! I wonder if I can move it or have it moved...

Comment: @Uchihaltachi: I edited the problem. If the input *is* a whole odd integer (e.g. 3.00), then the code can consider it the lower of the two odd numbers to be averaged. How would you adjust?

Comment: Beautiful! I'm going to mark this as the answer, although I'm interested to see if anyone comes up with anything as succinct as this in Python or Ruby.

Comment: Interestingly, that exact same construction in Ruby does not return 4, it returns 2. I'm going to find out why!

Comment: Found it. Ruby construct I was dividing by 2 instead of 2.0. Result of the division wasn't the float I needed.

Comment: i haven't worked in ruby , but i reckon ruby has an integer data type but javas cript does not . So , in my opinion 3/2 is 1 in ruby whereas it is 1.5 in javascript  floor of 1.5 is 2 whereas floor of 1 is 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working answer in Ruby.

### Ruby

```
def calculate_the_things(float)
      gt = 0
      if float % 1 == 0
        return (float + (float + 2))/2
      else
        lt = 0
      end

      rounded = float.round
      rounded > result ? gt = rounded + 1 : lt = rounded - 1
      if gt % 2 == 0
        gt += 1
      end
      if lt % 2 == 0
        lt -= 1
      end
      (gt + lt) / 2
end
```

**EDIT**

This is the succinct Ruby answer following UchihaItachi's pattern:

```
def calculate_the_things(float)
  2 * (float.floor/2.0).ceil
end
```

This is the succinct Python answer, following the same:

```
import math
def calculate_average(a):
    2 * math.ceil(math.floor(a) / 2)
```